# plotting highest point in a filled contour

Tags: matlab, plot, max, contour

Hi can somebody help me with the Matlab command here. I've got to determine the highest point in a filled contour I've plotted using matrix data in a file. And then I have to mark the highest point with a red `x`.

```
load('0101862_mod.dtm')   % loading the dtm file
X = X0101862_mod(1:81,:)  % we name X0101862, it is the location where the data X, Y and Z is stored
Y = X0101862_mod(82:162,:)
Z = X0101862_mod (163:243,:)

figure (1)
subplot(2,2,3)
[C,h] = contourf(X,Y,Z,10);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z'); title('X0101862_mod');
view(-73,34); axis equal; colormap summer; colorbar;
```

i know it involves `max` command. Kept getting error when i use `max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the red 'X', you have to call first `hold on` to make sure that the second plotting command won't erase the contour. Then, you use `plot(xMax,yMax,'xr')` to plot a red 'x' at the x/y coordinates where z is at its maximum.

To find `xMax` and `yMax`, you have to use the second output argument of `max`. [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) returns, as first output, the maximum (e.g. of `Z`), and as a second output, it returns the number of the element that is maximal. Use that number (the index) to find the elements in `X` and `Y` that correspond to the maximum `Z`-value, i.e. `xMax` and `yMax`.

Comment: is this correct?

xMax = max(X); yMax = max(Y);
plot(xMax,yMax, 'xr');

Comment: No. xMax is the X corresponding to the maximum Z. `[zMax,maxIdx] = max(Z);` returns, in `maxIdx` the location in the data vector where `Z` is highest. For example, if it is the 5th element in Z that is highest, `maxIdx` would be 5. Correspondingly, xMax would be the 5th element of `X`, and yMax the 5th element of `Y`.